# Why .WMV files have mime type 'video/x-ms-asf' instead of 'video/x-ms-wmv'?

Tags: django, html5-video, mime-types, content-type, libmagic

I need to accept only MP4 videos and WMV videos in a Django web app I am building. For that, I am checking the mime type of the file once it hits the server.

As far as I understand, MP4 files have 'video/mp4' mime type, which is exactly what I am receiving on my web app. The problem comes with the WMV files, which according to every site I found (e.g.: [this](http://help.encoding.com/knowledge-base/article/correct-mime-types-for-serving-video-files/) and [that](https://filext.com/file-extension/WMV)) should have 'video/x-ms-wmv' as the mime type.  When I get this files on the server and I inspect them using `python-magic` I get 'video/x-ms-asf' as its mime type.

I have converted some youtube videos to WMV videos using different online converters but the result is always the same.

So actually, I do not know what am I doing wrong here.

1. Maybe I have a problem of concets, where WMV videos can also have 'video/x-ms-asf' mime type, and not only 'video/x-ms-wmv'
2. Maybe `python-magic` is not reading the mime type correctly, which I think would be hardly the case.

Any help is deeply appreciated.

As a side note, I am using `python-magic` instead of django's `file.content_type` because the second is not reliable. Just change the file's extension to the wrong one and `file.content_type` will give the extention mime type instead of the real one.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`video/x-ms-asf` is the correct MIME type as it is a catch-all for Windows Media files containing audio and video under the "Advanced System Format" family name.

Within the 'family', Audio only files (.wma) can use `audio/x-ms-wma` and Video/Audio files (.wmv) can use `video/x-ms-wmv`, but for content optimized for streaming it is common to reference the container family rather than the file extension in the MIME type.

Answer (score 0):

If `python-magic` wraps well-known [`libmagic`](https://github.com/file/file) library, the reason is in that `libmagic` actually can't determine the content of ASF files: https://bugs.astron.com/view.php?id=84